# how to get a post from a href javascript button

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

im using a template to make my project and there is a button which is a (a href ) styled button

I want it use it as post in php to pull data .. but its not working . this is the button

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <span class="link1">
        <a href="" class="button1" id ="hide" name="submit"><strong>Search</strong></a>
    </span>
</div>
```

and i want to use it here ...

```
<?php

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
  echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This button works")</script>';
}

?>
```

but it does not seem to work ..plz help

Comment: where is java involved?

Comment: POST variables will not work for `href`'s, use an input instead or a submit type button. `href` is **not** a button. Plus, you have no named element called `from`.

Comment: i have downloaded this template .. im not quite sure where the java for this a href is put.. is there ny other solution ..if i could replace this whit any other code ?

Comment: `<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Search">` or `<button type="submit" name="submit">Search</button>` there. The other way would be to use a GET method for an `href`. Plus, you need form tags.

Comment: thats wat i am using for now :P  but i lose the design of the template .. :P

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you were referring to javascript instead of Java.

They are not the same.

But yes you could use javascript to submit the form using that anchor.

But first, you need to make sure that you have a form tag inside that markup.

Then bind an event on that anchor:

```
<?php

if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
    echo '<script type="text/javascript">alert("This button works")</script>';
}

?>

<div class="wrapper">
    <form method="POST" id="your_form_id">
        <span class="link1">
            <a href="#" class="button1" id="hide"><strong>Search</strong></a>
        </span>
    </form>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
document.getElementById('hide').addEventListener('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    document.getElementById('your_form_id').submit();
});
</script>
```

- [**Simple Demo**](http://codepad.viper-7.com/jFj0VS)

FYI: If you want a value to be passed, either utilize hidden input tags. Or put a value attribute and instead use a button.

Comment: Thankx bro .. i'll try it out ..d get back to u .. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
 if(isset($_POST['submit']))
```

it is false , as you have not submit any form.
Either make it

or add javascript/jquery form submit when clicking on href button.

Hope it helps.

[Your May see this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_get_post.htm)